# How to mutate an object inside array in react.js state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-state

I have an issue when i trying to updating the state.
here is my code:

```
const [todos, setTodos]= useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  setTodos([
{id:1, title: '', 
notes: [{id: 1, description: 'this is a simple description'}]}
])
}, [])
```

my goal is to add a note to the array of todos.
i try like this

```
const i = todos.findIndex((t) => t.id === parseInt(id));
const newArr = todos[i].notes[0].push(note);
setTasks(newArr);
```

but it's not working the newArr gives me the index note the new state.
Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get it working you can do something like below:

```
const newArr = todos[i].notes.push(note)
```

but it's not the recommended way.

The best way to add new item in to your notes array is to use `object.assign` or spread operator in order to not directly mutate your entire array. some thing like below:

```
const newArr = [...todos[i], note]
```

and also use this way of mutating your entire tasks array.

I think it's been well-described ar [here](https://medium.com/@fknussel/arrays-objects-and-mutations-6b23348b54aa) if you want to get more information around why you should use spread operator instead of push.

Comment: but if you noticed that the notes is also an array so i think it needs the brackets ? todos[i].notes[0]

Comment: I think no, because by using this way `[...todos[i], note]` and assigning it to setTasks it will replace the whole arrays of notes with older values already

Answer (score -1):

I have created [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-galileo-rtz8d) which works perfectly. What you have to do is to obtain the todo id and push to its note. Here the `todo` state gets updated but render method is not called. In order to call the `render` method I have called `setTodo` again.

Comment: Why you do it like this?  setTodo((prevTodo) => [...prevTodo]) ??  you didn't use _todo

Comment: Yes I didn't have to use `_todo` because `push` method has already mutated the `_todo`. That means `todo` state's value has been updated but that is not reflected in `render`. You can use log `todo` after pushing a note and will find the new note has been added. Just to render the `todo` I have called `setTodo` with its previous value which has been updated.

Comment: but the push function return index instead of the object

Comment: Here there is nothing to do with the return value of push method. By using push method _todo object's notes has been updated i.e. new note has been updated.